# Apache open custom page depending on ip

Tags: apache-httpd, ip, webserver

I have a apache. There is a config file:

```
      <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %b %{%d/%m/%y}t" bandwidth
      ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
      CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
      CustomLog /var/log/httpd/bandwidth.log bandwidth
  </VirtualHost>
```

And i have a text file, where stored ip-s, and that list can be modified in time from script file, which monitoring bandwidth by ip, and if ip reached a limit , the monitoring service add ip in text file.
How can i redirect request to static "limit.php" file, when some ip reach limit.

The monitoring service is a script in bash , which calculate bandwidth from /var/log/httpd/bandwidth.log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) and then write a [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) that meet your interests.